# How can I save changes in a deep nested object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the next data:

```
reservations = {
"2016":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests", "notes_backend":"Some notes 111"}},
"2017":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests", "notes_backend":"Some notes 222"}}
}
```

I need to change some `notes_backend` and then send updated `reservations` to API.

Here is my code:

```
var reservations_obj = JSON.parse(reservations),
    raw_id = 'A36822';

for (var year in reservations_obj){
    if (raw_id in reservations_obj[year]){
        reservations_obj[year][raw_id]["notes_backend"] = "UPDATED NOTES";
        console.log('new_data:', reservations_obj[year][raw_id]); // new_data: {datetime: "6/22/17 at 11:00AM", visitors: "11 guests", notes_backend: "UPDATED NOTES"}
        console.log(JSON.stringify(reservations_obj)); // no changes
        break;
    }
}

... send updated reservations_obj to API
```

The first `console.log` shows that `reservations_obj[year][raw_id]` is changed, but the second `console.log` shows me initial `reservations_obj` without any updates.

The code above is based on Python logic, but how to implement it in JavaScript?

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is the problem, because your code is already javascript implementation.

Comment: Please pay attention to the comments in the code. The first `console.log` shows that `reservations_obj[year][raw_id]` is changed, but the second `console.log` shows me initial `reservations_obj` without any updates.

Comment: If I remove the syntax errors caused by using the wrong symbol for "start of comment" for the language, it appears to work fine. What's the problem? (Voting to close off-topic as being caused by a typo)

Comment: This is the output your code is giving me: `{"2016":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests","notes_backend":"UPDATED NOTES"}},"2017":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests","notes_backend":"Some notes 222"}}}` (if I convert reservations to a string rather than an object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had few syntax mistakes. First of all JSON must be a string:

```
var reservations = `{
"2016":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests", "notes_backend":"Some notes 111"}},
"2017":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests", "notes_backend":"Some notes 222"}}
}`
```

here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FvbedPv4jnQd3yA4r0kT?p=preview) with almost the same code. (open console)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine.. but have in mind that the reservations variable already contains PARSED json.

```
var reservations = {
"2016":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests", "notes_backend":"Some notes 111"}},
"2017":{"A36822":{"datetime":"6/22/17 at 11:00AM","visitors":"11 guests", "notes_backend":"Some notes 222"}}
}

// var reservations_obj = JSON.parse(reservations),     // reservations is already PARSED!
var reservations_obj = reservations,
    raw_id = 'A36822';

for (var year in reservations_obj){
    if (raw_id in reservations_obj[year]){
        reservations_obj[year][raw_id]["notes_backend"] = "UPDATED NOTES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        console.log(JSON.stringify(reservations_obj));
        break;
    }
}
```